# @font-face not working in firefox only

Tags: firefox, css

Using this @font-face css.  works in Chrome, Safari, and IE, only not Firefox.  All required files are uploaded to the server.

CSS:

> ```
> @font-face {
>         font-family: 'Calgary';
>       src: url('../fonts/calgary.eot');
>       src: url('../fonts/calgary.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
>                  url('../fonts/calgary.woff') format('woff'),
>                  url('../fonts/calgary.ttf') format('truetype');
>       font-weight: normal;
>       font-style: normal;
> }
>
> #header-text-webform {
>   position: relative;
>   top: 59px;
>   left: 20px;
>   font-family: 'Calgary', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif !important;
>   color: white;
>   font-size: 26px;
>   font-weight: normal;
>   text-transform: uppercase;
>   z-index: 1;
> }
> ```

Comment: Any resource loading issues? Seems like a weird issue if it's only happening in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duplicate src declaration. Remove this line:

```
src: url('../fonts/calgary.eot');
```

and see if that helps at all. If Firefox only reads this, first, `src` definition, it will be trying to load an EOT font which it doesn't support...

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following structure and have no issues in firefox (or anything else)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calgary';
    src: url('/fonts/calgary.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/calgary.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/calgary.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/calgary.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/calgary.svg#calgary') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```